# как узнать id элемента

Tags: jquery

Такая проблема:

посредством `id_ = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");`

я узнаю `id` копируемого элемента. Пишу условие `if (id_ == "drag1"){console.log("это объект drag1"); }`.

но данное условие не работает, в чем проблема?

Comment: Смотря чему равен $(ui.draggable).attr("id"). HTML код примера добавьте в вопрос?

Comment: и еще добавьте описание того, что такое `ui`, `ui.draggable`

Answer (score 1):

проблема еще заключалась в том, что я использовала плагин jsPlumb, и код всей программы начинался с `jsPlumb.ready(function() { ... });`
Просто поменяла на `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Работающий пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#artCanvas").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      var id_ = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
      console.log(id_);

      if (id_ == "drag1") {
        alert(" это drag1");
      }

      var www = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('objectDrag');
      www.draggable();
      $(this).append(www);
      www.draggable({
        containment: 'parent'
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.objectDrag {} #artCanvas {
  background-image: url("https://sivers.org/images/blank.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 451px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content" class="row">

    <div class="objectDrag">
      <img id="drag1" class="item" src="http://www.drupal.ru/files/imagecache/96x96/pictures/picture-41225.jpg">
      <img id="drag2" class="item" src="http://www.vista-style-icons.com/libs/smile/indifference-icon.gif" />
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="artCanvas"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: стоит добавить пояснение, что же именно не работало и как починилось

Comment: проблема еще заключалась в том что я использовала плагин jsPlumb и код всей программы начинался с  jsPlumb.ready(function() {}); Просто поменяла на $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Это условие не работает, потому что `id_` не равен `"drag1"`

Comment: у меня несколько объектов, которые я могу копировать. id каждого элемента = drag1, drag2 и т.д. вот именно, когда я копирую элемент с id=drag1 должно выводится, что это объект drag1

Comment: @Светлана, значит вы копируете не `drag1` :-) судя по предоставленному коду - значение `id` не равно `drag1` именно по этому условие не работает.

Comment: попробую сделать пример) может серьезно в этом и ошибка

Comment: все нашла свою ошибку, спасибо)Все работает правильно, просто denver глючил)

Comment: @Светлана, и в чем она заключалась? :)

Comment: отправила пример) все работает

Comment: Вот такой вопрос: а как можно узнать id элементов (дочерних), находящихся в #artCanvas?

Comment: @Светлана, можно взять его детей [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) выбрать из них `id`: `idsObj = art.children().map(function(){return this.id;})`, и привести в массив: `ids = idsObj.toArray()`

Comment: спасибо, поняла)